# PostgreSQL Same Table Left Outer Join With Multiple Tables

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I have a table which needs to left outer joined with two different tables. When I put the table twice in the query and join it with it self in the where clause (like the sentence below) it works. I think this should not be the correct way. How can I write the select statement and outer join the table with multiple different tables?

```
SELECT cols."COLUMN_NAME"
     , COALESCE(translations."COLUMN_LANG_TITLE",cols."COLUMN_TITLE") AS "COLUMN_TITLE" 
     , options."OPTION_DESC"
  FROM 

"EXTAPP_SETUP"."OBJECT_COLUMNS_TAB" cols LEFT OUTER JOIN "EXTAPP_SETUP"."COLUMN_LANG_TITLES_TAB" translations
        ON translations."EXTAPP_ID" = cols."EXTAPP_ID" and translations."OBJECT_NAME" = cols."OBJECT_NAME" and translations."COLUMN_NAME" = cols."COLUMN_NAME" and translations."LANGUAGE_CODE" = 'fr',

"EXTAPP_SETUP"."OBJECT_COLUMNS_TAB" cols2 LEFT OUTER JOIN "EXTAPP_SETUP"."COL_FIX_OPTIONS_TAB" options
        ON options."EXTAPP_ID" = cols2."EXTAPP_ID" and options."OBJECT_NAME" = cols2."OBJECT_NAME" and options."COLUMN_NAME" = cols2."COLUMN_NAME" 

WHERE cols."EXTAPP_ID" = cols2."EXTAPP_ID" and cols."OBJECT_NAME" = cols2."OBJECT_NAME" and cols."COLUMN_NAME" = cols2."COLUMN_NAME"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use subsequent left joins.
Since you are not realy using your cols2 table, you can eliminate it from the query. This would also eliminate the `where` clause, because you don't need to join the cols table with itself

```
SELECT cols."COLUMN_NAME"
  , COALESCE(translations."COLUMN_LANG_TITLE",cols."COLUMN_TITLE") AS "COLUMN_TITLE" 
  , options."OPTION_DESC"
FROM "EXTAPP_SETUP"."OBJECT_COLUMNS_TAB" cols 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "EXTAPP_SETUP"."COLUMN_LANG_TITLES_TAB" translations
  ON translations."EXTAPP_ID" = cols."EXTAPP_ID" 
    and translations."OBJECT_NAME" = cols."OBJECT_NAME" 
    and translations."COLUMN_NAME" = cols."COLUMN_NAME" 
    and translations."LANGUAGE_CODE" = 'fr' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "EXTAPP_SETUP"."COL_FIX_OPTIONS_TAB" options
  ON options."EXTAPP_ID" = cols."EXTAPP_ID" 
    and options."OBJECT_NAME" = cols."OBJECT_NAME" 
    and options."COLUMN_NAME" = cols."COLUMN_NAME"
```